# ANTLR properly detecting mode for 1st line

Tags: antlr4

I have the following parser

```
parser grammar T5Parser ;

options {
    tokenVocab = T5Lexer ;
}

root: line (EOL? line)* EOL? EOF;

line: commandLine | dataLine  ;

dataLine: CDataLine;

commandLine: StartCmd+ command ;

command
    : halt
    | note
    | read
    | end
;

halt    :   CHALT ;
end     :   CEND DataLine? ;
note    :   CNOTE DataLine? ;
read    :   CREAD fileName=StringLiteral ;
```

and Lexer

```
lexer grammar T5Lexer ;

StartCmd: '@';

CDataLine: BOL ~'@' ~[\r\n]+;

EOL:                EOL_F -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE);

WS:     [ \t]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
BOL :   [\r\n\f]+ ;

DOT:   [.];
COMMA: ',';

CHALT  :  'HALT' ;
CEND   :  'END'  -> pushMode(DataMode);
CNOTE  :  'NOTE' -> pushMode(DataMode);
CREAD  :  'READ';

StringLiteral       :   DblQuotedString | SglQuotedString;

fragment DblQuotedString    :   [C]*'"' ( '\\'. | '""' | ~('"'| '\\') )* '"';
fragment SglQuotedString    :   [C]*'\'' ('\\'. | '\'\'' | ~('\'' | '\\'))* '\'';
fragment BackQuotedString   :   [C]*'`' ( '\\'. | '``' | ~('`'|'\\'))* '`';

//=======================================
mode DataMode     ;

DmPOP :   [ ,] -> popMode;
DmEOL:    EOL_F -> type(EOL), popMode;
DataLine: ( ~[\r\n]*? '-' EOL_F)* ~[\r\n]+;

//=======================================
fragment NL:         '\r'? '\n';
fragment EOL_F:      [ ]* NL;
```

working fine for the following aspects of the parsed syntax

- Commands start with an @
- Commands can have parameters (READ as an example here) or optional
  comments
- Lines that don't start with an @ are "free form" inline data to be
  consumed as is

  Sample input

```
@NOTE 
@NOTE with data
@READ 'file.one'
Test data line
@END
@HALT
```

Maybe there are better ways to match a "line does not start with something", alas that's the best I've been able to come up with after hours of searching, but with this solution
the aspect I just can't get a grip on is when "free form data" appears on the first line of input and there's no BOL.

Any hints on how I can get around this ?

TIA - Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would do the trick:

```
lexer grammar T5Lexer;

CommandStart
 : '@' -> mode(CommandMode)
 ;

DataLine
 : ~[@\r\n] ~[\r\n]*
 ;

EOL
 : [ \t]* ( '\r'? '\n' | '\r' )
 ;

mode CommandMode;

 HALT          : 'HALT' ;
 END           : 'END'  -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE);
 NOTE          : 'NOTE' -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE);
 READ          : 'READ';
 Spaces        : [ \t]+ -> skip;
 StringLiteral : '\'' ( '\'\'' | ~['\r\n] )* '\'';
 CM_NewLine    : EOL -> type(EOL), mode(DEFAULT_MODE);
```

with he parser grammar:

```
parser grammar T5Parser;

options {
 tokenVocab=T5Lexer;
}

root
 : line ( EOL+ line )* EOL* EOF
 ;

line
 : commandLine
 | DataLine
 ;

commandLine
 : CommandStart command
 ;

command
 : halt
 | note
 | read
 | end
 ;

halt : HALT;
end  : END DataLine?;
note : NOTE DataLine?;
read : READ StringLiteral;
```

which would parse the input:

```
first line
@NOTE 
@NOTE with data
@READ 'file.one'
Test data line
@END
@HALT
```

like this:

[image]

Comment: Beautiful, thanks !

Forgot one detail, the syntax allows for multiple @ starting a command for denoting procedure nesting levels, but I've solved this aspect myself.

Comment: You're welcome, and good to hear you solved the multiple @'s yourself!